# Using knitr package to output with stitch(), remove the top HTML marketing line

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

I have used knitr and the stitch() functionality to provide code (including graphs and outputs) for grad class assignments. This functionality would be great natively in RStudio. I would like to remove the top line of marketing from knitr's html template. The template is "knitr-template.Rhtml", question is where do i find it/must it reside to be utilised?

```
{This report is automatically generated with the R package knitr (version 1.10.5) }

{Assignment One -}
```

Comment: mebbe `system.file("misc", "knitr-template.Rhtml", package = "knitr")` like it says in the help for `stitch()`?

Comment: Thanks hrbrmstr - trying to find knits-template.Rhtml?

Comment: If you're following the example in the help for `stitch()` then it's `knitr-template.Rhtml` and it's in that location (run that command). There is no built- in `knits-template.Rhtml`.

Comment: I think this is the 'compile notebook' button in recent versions of RStudio?